# How works autologin in SE websites?

Tags: discussion, login

I am quite often on SO, but sometimes I use to be on other SE websites like askubuntu, serverfault...

I don't know how it works (cookies, IP ??), but sometimes the SE website (where I'm not yet connected) shows me a message :

> Hey kmas, Click here to login !

*[I don't remember exactly the message...]*

---

When I click on that message, I am **automatically connected** (great feature !).

But sometimes, this message doesn't appear and I have to **login manually**...

**I would like to know why or what I have did that makes it not working ?**

---

**Extra information :** I have a Stack Exchange and a Google login for this account...

Comment: related on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/upcoming-login-changes-stage-2-and-the-new-ui-now-live

Comment: So now I know why it is not working on area51, askubuntu, superuser ! :) I just have to keep calm and wait for winter... for universal login ! Sorry. ;)